# How to filter complex array whose one property value is the same and the other property value is mas?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, filter

As title, purpose is to get array with no duplicated name and value is max.

```
var data=[{name:'A',value:3},{name:'B',value:5},{name:'A',value:7},{name:'B',value:1},{name:'B',value:12},{name:'A',value:4}];
```

expected output:

```
var newData=[];
newData=[{name:'A',value:7},{name:'B',value:12}];
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

**1. solution using [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), [Math.max](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max)**

```js
var data = [
  { name: "A", value: 3 },
  { name: "B", value: 5 },
  { name: "A", value: 7 },
  { name: "B", value: 1 },
  { name: "B", value: 12 },
  { name: "A", value: 4 },
];

const dict = {};
data.forEach(({ name, value }) => {
  dict[name] = Math.max(value, dict[name] ?? Number.MIN_VALUE);
});

const result = Object.entries(dict).map((o) => {
  const [name, value] = o;
  return { name, value };
});

console.log(result);
```

**2. Using simple forEach and if condition.**

```js
var data = [{
    name: "A",
    value: 3
  },
  {
    name: "B",
    value: 5
  },
  {
    name: "A",
    value: 7
  },
  {
    name: "B",
    value: 1
  },
  {
    name: "B",
    value: 12
  },
  {
    name: "A",
    value: 4
  },
];

const dict = {};
data.forEach(({ name, value }) => {
  if (dict[name]) {
    if (dict[name] < value) dict[name] = value;
  } else {
    dict[name] = value;
  }
});

const result = Object.entries(dict).map((o) => {
  const [name, value] = o;
  return { name, value };
});

console.log(result);
```